# how to get the name of the current file in the canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have whrite this code in Python 3.7

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


import random
def cmd():
    print("Files:", img1.cget("file"), img2.cget("file"))

    img = random.choice([img1, img2])
    can.itemconfig(log, image=img)


    print("Choice:", can.itemcget(log, "image"))


img1 = PhotoImage(file="a.gif")
img2 = PhotoImage(file="b.gif")

can = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg="white")
log = can.create_image(151, 151, image=None)
can.pack()

btt = Button(root, text="click", command=cmd)
btt.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

I would like to print the name of the image configured inside the Canvas

```
print("Files:", img1.cget("file"), img2.cget("file"))

Result > Files: a.gif b.gif < Return Filename OK

print("Choice:", can.itemcget(log, "image"))

Result > Choice: pyimage1 Or Choice: pyimage2 < Return String No OK
```

how can I do? thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with `img.cget('file')`. Or just keeping a reference for that matter?

Comment: the first print shows the possible choices that can come out,

the second print must show the random choice returned by the code

Comment: You will need to store the name of the chosen image separately.  The Canvas image item has no need for that information, and therefore doesn't store it anywhere.

Comment: thanks jasonharper for the answer

if, print ("Choice:", can.itemcget (log, "image")) returns pyimage1 etc.. as a string
can I take the image name from PhotoImage through the result of these strings?

Answer (score 0):

but it is not possible to get the file name with a reverse procedure?

example:

`print(PhotoImage(name="pyimage1"))`

return > a.gif